# https not working for virtual diractory

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, iis-7, virtual-directory

I configure the SSL for my website https://www.test.com. i had one virtual diractory in it `testwcf`. when i access it with https://www.test.com/testwcf/Common.svc. Message shown `You have created a service.` but when i access any method in service, for example
https://www.test.com/testwcf/Common.svc/select?id=1 i get the error `The resource cannot be found.`. but it works fine with http i.e.`http://www.test.com/testwcf/Common.svc/select?id=1`. Can anybody help me to solve this problem. I search on net alot but nothing work for me

Below is my websconfg

```
<services>

     <service name="testwcf.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="testwcf.IService1"/>

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the binding for your service to use transport security.  Add a secure binding like:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And then change your service config to use that binding.

```
<services>
  <service name="MySecureWCFService.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="MySecureWCFService.IService1"/>

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added this in my webconfig of wcf applicaion but didn't work

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant sections of your web config?